# org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a parent class which is a Visitor class which will have all the fields of a visitor. The class is as follows.

```
package classes.trantables;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Time;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import java.sql.Date;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;


@Entity
@Table(name="VISITORS")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Visitors implements  Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(nullable=false,name="COMPANY_ID")
    private String companyId;//Maps to company 
    @Id
    @Column(nullable=false,name="BRANCH_ID")
    private String branchId;//number of branches
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((branchId == null) ? 0 : branchId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((companyId == null) ? 0 : companyId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((passNo == null) ? 0 : passNo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Visitors)) {
            return false;
        }
        Visitors other = (Visitors) obj;
        if (branchId == null) {
            if (other.branchId != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!branchId.equals(other.branchId)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (companyId == null) {
            if (other.companyId != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!companyId.equals(other.companyId)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (passNo == null) {
            if (other.passNo != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!passNo.equals(other.passNo)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(nullable=false,name="PASS_NO")
    private String passNo;//Random generated
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String visitorName;//Name given by the visitor
    //remainder of the class is not required..
```

Now I want to create a class which is a child class to this class which stores all the belongings of the visitor.
I want the COMPANY_ID, BRANCH_ID,PASS_NO, from the VISITOR class and ItemName from the Belongings class to be the primary key for the Belongings class. I want a table per sub class but I am getting errors if i put the above class in mapping.

This is what I have tried, below..

```
package classes.trantables;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="BELONGINGS")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID",referencedColumnName="COMPANY_ID"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="BRANCH_ID",referencedColumnName="BRANCH_ID"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PASS_NO", referencedColumnName="PASS_NO")
})


public class Belongings extends Visitors{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String itemNm;
    private String model;
    private String srNo;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have another `@Id` annotated property in your subclass.  Removing `@Id` from `itemNm` in `Belongings` will get rid this Exception.

Comment: Hey..
I somehow want to make an Id attribute as itemNm here I need to do this. I have to store the states for the particular country...in this child table. I know the answer but somehow I want to do this..

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding as well, I have a different table with different entities (although they subclass) where literally the only thing that's different is the primary key and some internal behavior when it interfaces with the application.

edit: a little more info, I have a table that's saving what is effectively considered "drafts" which get a UUID instead of the custom generated ID that is normally applied to non-"drafts".